# Is there a standard notation distinguishing these two tensor algebras?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$.

Usually, we write $\mathscr{T}(V)$ to denote the tensor algebra $\oplus_{n=0}^\infty V^{\otimes n}$.

However, in differential geometry we meed another machinery also called the tensor algebra, i.e. $\oplus_{r,s\in\mathbb{N}} V^{\otimes r}\otimes (V^*) ^{\otimes s}$.

Is there a stanard notation to designate this latter tensor algebra to distinguish it from the notation for the usual tensor algebra $\mathscr{T}(V)$? And is there a specific name for this algebra?

Would it be okay to use $\mathscr{T}^*(V)$ to designate the latter one?

Comment: I would avoid the proposed notation using ${}^{\ast}$ because that symbol already has an incompatible universal meaning in linear algebra.

Comment: @Travis Okay.. then what notation would you prefer to designate that?

Comment: I don't know of a standard compact notation. One sometimes sees a notation like $T_{r, s}(V)$ for $V^{\otimes r} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s}$, so one could correspondingly write something like $\bigoplus_{r, s} T_{r, s}(V)$ for the object you have in mind.